# How to blur an image while showing text over it (hover) with css

Tags: html, css, image, animation, css-selectors

Okay, so. I have a problem.

I wanted to have a picture that blurred on hover, and at the same time making text appear over it.

I've found a simple way to blur the image and to make the text appear, but not both at the same time; in fact merging the two codes together make it appear as the picture isn't blurring at all. I think this is due to the fact that the text actually covers the image and the browser doesn't receive the message that the image is being hovered.

Here is [the image with text over it](http://nicolacornolti.com/tests/1.html) and here is [the image with blur on hover](http://nicolacornolti.com/tests/2.html)
How can I solve that issue? I'm struggling and i think I have found another way of doing it but it's a bit cumbersome.

Here is some code:

```css
 h1,p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .imgtext {  
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.89);
  width: 155px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 50px 15px 0 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
 }
 .pic {
    position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 185px;
  height: 185px;
  margin: 50px auto;
 }
 .pic img:hover{
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
 }
 .imgtext:hover {
  -webkit-opacity: 100;
  opacity: 100;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="pic">
  <img src="http://nicolacornolti.com/photos/film/img/1.png">
  <span class="imgtext">
   <h1>THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
   <p>and this is a description</p>
  </span>
```

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/0qbxxyke/2/

Answer (score 5):

Use the pseudo class `:hover` on the `.pic` container element, and not on each individual child element.

**For example:**

`.pic .imgtext:hover` to `.pic:hover .imgtext`

and

`.pic img:hover` to `.pic:hover img`

```css
h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.imgtext {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
  width: 155px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 50px 15px 0 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.pic {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 185px;
  height: 185px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.pic:hover img {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.pic:hover .imgtext {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://nicolacornolti.com/photos/film/img/1.png">
  <span class="imgtext">
    <h1>THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
    <p>and this is a description</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all your text-span was missing a `left` position setting, which i added (`0`). Apart from that, I changed the selectors for the hover state so that the image and the text settings both change when their *parent*  element `.pic` is hovered:

```css
h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.imgtext {
  color: white;
  width: 155px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 50px 15px 0 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.pic {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 185px;
  height: 185px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.pic:hover img {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.pic:hover .imgtext {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://nicolacornolti.com/photos/film/img/1.png">
  <span class="imgtext">
   <h1>THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
   <p>and this is a description</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't spend too much time setting the layout, I just wanted to post the basics of the animation.

Anyway thank you very much for answering and clarifying why it should have been written this way

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/DannaB67/pen/JJJQqX

```css
h1,p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.imgtext {  
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  width: 155px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 50px 15px 0 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.pic {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 185px;
  height: 185px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.pic:hover img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scale(1.08);
}
.imgtext:hover {
  -webkit-opacity: 40;
  opacity: 40;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://nicolacornolti.com/photos/film/img/1.png">
  <span class="imgtext">
   <h1>THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
   <p>and this is a description</p>
  </span>
</div>
```